# Organize/Formatting the python code to one line

Tags: python, list, for-loop, nested

Is there any way to rewrite the below python code in one line

```
for i in range(len(main_list)):
  if main_list[i] != []:
   for j in range(len(main_list[i])):
     main_list[i][j][6]=main_list[i][j][6].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

something like below,

```
 [main_list[i][j][6]=main_list[i][j][6].strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for i in range(len(main_list)) if main_list[i] != [] for j in range(len(main_list[i]))]
```

I got SyntaxError for this.

Actually, i'm trying to storing all the values fetched from table into one list. Since the table contains date method/datatype, my requirement needs to convert it to string as i faced with malformed string error.

So my approach is to convert that element of list from datetime.date() to str. And i got it working. Just wanted it to work with one line

Comment: What's `all_issues`? Can you provide some sample input data, i.e. a [mcve]?

Comment: sorry that was a typo.. it should be main_list and not all_issues.. I have corrected the above snippet.  

and it would be something like below,
main_list=[[],[],[[x,y,z,datetime.date(2016, 8, 18),type1],[a,b,c,datetime.date(2016, 8, 18),type1]],[],[]]

Comment: What's your desired output? Do you need `main_list` updated or do you want to create a new list with just `datetime` objects? A list comprehension will create a *new* list.

Comment: yes.. i need the main_list to be updated. replace the element that has value datetime.date(2016,8,18) to '2016-8-18'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a syntax error because you're not allowed to perform assignments within a list comprehension. Python forbids assignments because it is discouraging over complex list comprehensions in favour of for loops.

Obviously you shouldn't do this on one line, but this is how to do it:

```
import datetime

# Example from your comment:
type1 = "some type"
main_list = [[], [],
             [[1, 2, 3, datetime.date(2016, 8, 18), type1],
              [3, 4, 5, datetime.date(2016, 8, 18), type1]], [], []]


def fmt_times(lst):
    """Format the fourth value of each element of each non-empty sublist"""
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        if lst[i] != []:
            for j in range(len(lst[i])):
                lst[i][j][3] = lst[i][j][3].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    return lst


def fmt_times_one_line(main_list):
    """Format the fourth value of each element of each non-empty sublist"""
    return [[] if main_list[i] == [] else [[main_list[i][j][k] if k != 3 else main_list[i][j][k].strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for k in range(len(main_list[i][j]))] for j in range(len(main_list[i])) ] for i in range(len(main_list))]

import copy

# Deep copy needed because fmt_times modifies the sublists.
assert fmt_times(copy.deepcopy(main_list)) == fmt_times_one_line(main_list)
```

The list comprehension is a functional thing. If you know how map() works in python or javascript then it's the same thing. In a map() or comprehension we generally don't mutate the data we're mapping over (and python discourages attempting it) so instead we recreate the entire object, substituting only the values we wanted to modify.

Answer (score 3):

#### Use the explicit `for` loop. There's no better option.

A list comprehension is used to create a **new** list, not to modify certain elements of an existing list.

You may be able to update values via a list comprehension, e.g. `[L.__setitem__(i, 'some_value') for i in range(len(L))]`, but this is not recommended as you are using a side-effect and in the process creating a list of `None` values which you then discard.

You could also write a convoluted list comprehension with a ternary statement indicating when you meet the 6th element in a 3rd nested sublist. But this will make your code difficult to maintain.

In short, use the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

One line?

```
main_list = convert_list(main_list)
```

You will have to put a few more lines somewhere else though:

```
def convert_list(main_list):
    for i, ml in enumerate(main_list):
        if isinstance(ml, list) and len(ml) > 0:
            main_list[i] = convert_list(ml)
        elif isinstance(ml, datetime.date):
            main_list[i] = ml.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    return main_list
```

You might be able to whack this together with a list comprehension but it's a terrible idea (for reasons better explained in the other answer).